# Meaning of "for their input"

Tags: meaning

My advisor told me to "share this report with Tom for his input"

What does my advisor mean here by "for his input"? Does he means to allow Tom to add his part in this report or does he means to allow Tom to read and know the information contained in this report?

The background is Tom should have no idea what's going on in this report but he knows what I am doing for a big picture.

Of course, Tom is a random name here...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your advisor wants you to do is let Tom read it and ask what he thinks - if he has anything to add to your report or if he thinks the report should be submitted as it is already written.

However, does your advisor know that Tom shouldn't know about what is going on in the report? If your advisor doesn't know maybe you should have told them that.

Ultimately, what you do is up to you. Your advisor is suggesting that you should let Tom read the report and suggest changes (which, of course, you don't have to make).

Answer (score 2):

Tom's exact [input](http://thefreedictionary.com/input) will vary depending on Tom's role, but your advisor is telling you to share the report with Tom for him to add to/collaborate with/feedback on your work.

His input could add to your report, or it might consist of proofreading/error-checking your work.

Tom will read the report, and report back to you with his findings/opinion.

Sometimes I'm asked for my input on reports on topics I don't know very well - in those cases my role is of that of a proof-reader.
Other times, I have an intimate knowledge of the topic and my role is to comment on the quality, length, accuracy and focus of the project.